# How to Get DPI of Image in C#

Tags: c#, dpi

how can i get dpi of an image using asp.net c#

Comment: see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207187/how-can-i-get-the-resolution-of-an-image-jpeg-gif-png-jpg

Answer (score 27):

How about `Image.HorizontalResolution` and `Image.VerticalResolution`? Like this:

```
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("TestImage.bmp");
var dpiX = image.HorizontalResolution;
var dpiY = image.VerticalResolution;
```

Comment: The property comment says that that's _pixels_ per Inch, though... not dots per inch. Not sure if there's a difference...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207187/how-can-i-get-the-resolution-of-an-image-jpeg-gif-png-jpg), which sources it's code from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/2D-Graphics/GetImageResolutionandImagesizeandDisplaysize.htm):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

namespace BitmapDpi
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("winter.jpg");
            Console.WriteLine("Image resolution: " + bmp.HorizontalResolution + "DPI");
        }
    }
}
```