# How to convert PropertyItem(Horizontal resolution) value to integer?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, exif

```
    var bmpOutput = new Bitmap(@"1_0.jpg");

    foreach (var item in bmpOutput.PropertyItems)
    {
        var id = item.Id; // 20625
        var length = item.Len; // 128
        var type = item.Type; // 3 ( MSDN says that 3 : Specifies that Value is an array of unsigned short (16-bit) integers.
        var byteArray = item.Value; // length 128

        var result = BitConverter.ToUInt16(byteArray, 0); // 1 but must be 96
    }
```

I try to retrieve image dpi, but I can't convert the byte array to an integer value.
I want to get vertical and horizontal resolution from jpg(96x96).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The properties that you need are in the Image class, a Bitmap inherits from it so:

```
var dpiX = ((Image)bmpOutput).HorizontalResolution;
var dpiY = ((Image)bmpOutput).VerticalResolution;
```

Can also check:
[How to Get DPI of Image in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054540/how-to-get-dpi-of-image-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Do you have any clue why not?
Special image?

Comment: It works wrong for me, I have a dpi awareness application, so when I use your solution it anyway shows 144 dpi, but the image has 96

Comment: Checked with several images, works fine...
Have you tried with other images?
Maybe something's wrong with that image, can you send it?